# How can I make a waterfall Q promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q, deferred

let's take this as an example:

- I have 3 urls in an array urls
- require function returns a promise which just makes an $http call

this is a working code, but as the array can be '1 to n' this is obviously not what I want.
I need the 3 require as a waterfall, not in parallel.
in the last promise, I need to resolve a final promise which is the var deferred.

```
require(urls[0]).then(function () {                            
    require(urls[1]).then(function () {                                
        require(urls[2]).then(function () {                                    
            deferred.resolve();
        });
    });
})
```

this approach is not working, because this will do all the $http calls in parallel.

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(urls, function (value) {
    promises.push(require(value));
});
$q.all(promises).then(function () {
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

is there a nice way to do this with a for/cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a function to handle the iterations:

```
function go (urls) {
    if (urls[0]) {
      require(urls[0]).then(function () {
          go(urls.slice(1));
      });
    }
}

go(urls);
```

Comment: should be: function go(urls, i){ ... }

Comment: there's a breaking } in go(urls, ++i)};

Comment: No problem. I simplified it to remove the `i` parameter and fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent blog post: http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/

I will share only the part that is relevant.

First we define this helper method:

```
function serial(tasks) {
  var prevPromise;
  angular.forEach(tasks, function (task) {
    //First task
    if (!prevPromise) { 
      prevPromise = task(); 
    } else {
      prevPromise = prevPromise.then(task); 
    }
  });
  return prevPromise;
}
```

Then we use it.

```
serial([
  function() { return require(urls[0]) },
  function() { return require(urls[1]) },
  function() { return require(urls[2]) }
]).then(function () {
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

Comment: I also like your answer man, but the other one was genious :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer another way, there's a ["one-line" solution](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences) to this without having to make another method:

```
return promises.reduce($q.when, promises[0]);
```

See demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xlGxYj57lzXdAMM5Iv6s?p=preview (I changed the default `$q.when` to something else to show handling each promise.)

Update: Made the plunker more representative of OP's scenario.

Comment: wouldn't that trigger the first promise twice, however?